# Why do i get the NullPointerException error with my array?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

My program runs. Its just that in the middle of the program it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Example.main(Example.java:33)
```

Here is my code:

```
String [] iArray ;
String i ;
int counter=1 ; counteragain=-1, q;

do {
System.out.print ("\n\nItem Code : ") ;
i = s.next();

if (i.equals ("0") ){
  counter = 0 ;
} else {
  System.out.print ("\nQuantity: ") ;
q = s.nextInt() ;
counteragain++ ;

i = iArray[counteragain];
}
} while (counter!=0) ;
```

The line where I'm getting the error is:

```
 i = iArray[counteragain];
```

Why do I get this error? Is my syntax wrong? But then why does it run my program?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: iArray is not assigned with any value yet.

Comment: What is `s`? It is never declared.

Answer (score 3):

You did not initialize this Array. Therefore it has a *null* value.
You have to do something like this

```
String[] iArray = new String[numberOfElements];
```

You do **not** need to initialize the array in the declaration. So you can first recollect this *numberOfElements* and then initialize it.

```
iArray = new String[numberOfElements];
```

Answer (score 2):

`String [] iArray ;` is never instantiated. So, initially, `iArray` is null.

When you're getting an element `i = iArray[counteragain];`, you're trying to access an uninstantiated array, so a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

I don't know what's your array size, but to un-nullify it, you will have to do:

```
String[] iArray = new String[size];
```

Now, `iArray` will have a placeholder of length `size` but each element will be `null` as it hasn't been assigned a value. i.e., `iArray[0]` will be null as there is no value at element `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`iArray` is never initialized. So the dereferenced `iArray[counteragain]` does so with a null reference; hence the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate the array.
the line `String [] iArray` ; only declared a reference to an array of type string but did not
allocate any room for objects in the array;
you need to change that line to something like

```
String[] iArray = new String[size of needed array];
```

if you cant predict the needed size, it might be better to use a collection type like ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not complete, it does not show what s is (I guess it is an iterator) and where it came from. 
From the code you posted the Exception is the consequence of

```
String [] iArray;
```

You did not initialize iArray so it's null; you should post a working method/class in order to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

`iArray = new String[n];`, where `n` is the number of elements in `iArray`.

Should help you get rid of `NullPointerException`..